# Xtext ecore file can't be loaded

Tags: java, xtext, emf, ecore

My Xtext Editor throws `com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
1) Error injecting method, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError ....` during opening.

It's...

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: MyDsl.ecore
at com.sample.impl.MyDslPackageImpl.loadPackage(MyDslPackageImpl.java:5989)
at com.sample.impl.MyDslPackageImpl.init(MyDslPackageImpl.java:1098)
at com.sample.MyDslPackage.<clinit>(MyDslPackage.java:58)
... 75 more
```

The MyDsl.ecore file resides in the `model/generated` and also in the `src-gen` folders `com.sample.impl` package. So it's physically at the right place. But anyway the `loadPackage` method of `MyDslPackageImpl.java` can't load it.

Does anyone have an idea what may be the reason and how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
**The reason was the *.ecores file size.**

**Solution:** split the grammar into seperate projects and import one into the other.

Nice tutorial how to do so at: http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/xtext-referencing-elements-of-one-dsl-from-another-dsl/

Comment: Does anyone know why there is this ecore file size limit and how to avoid splitting the grammar?